# RSI Above/below for previous bar tradingview Pines script

Tags: pine-script

Hi i want my script to look back 1 bar or 2 bars and if RSI was OS or OB to continue with script but i can't find anything to work like that

```
if (RSIOverBought = close[2])
...
```

(i know this can't work is just for easier understanding)

Answer (score 3):

The following code shows an example on how to reference a previous rsi value.

```
//@version=4
study("RSI Barcolor",overlay=false)

length   = input(15, "Length")
lookback = input(2, "Lookback")
ob       = input(70, "Overbought")
os       = input(30, "Oversold")

rsi = rsi(close, length)

var color col = na
if crossover(rsi[lookback], ob)
    // do something here...
    col := color.aqua
if crossunder(rsi[lookback], os)
    // do something here...
    col := color.yellow
if crossover(rsi[lookback], os) or crossunder(rsi[lookback], ob)
    col := na

barcolor(col,offset=-lookback)

plot(rsi)
hline(ob)
hline(os)
```